# How to inject Layout to LayoutInflater in RoboGuice?

Tags: android, roboguice

I have layout

```
R.layout.alarm_clock_setting_view
```

And i want to Inject him into LayoutInflater.

Now i do next :

```
@InjectView(R.layout.alarm_clock_setting_view)
private RelativeLayout alarmClockSettingView;

...
//in OnCreate
 mSettingAlarmClockView = alarmClockSettingView;
...
```

But that's not worked. What i need to do to inject layout into LayoutInflater?

Error :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samsung.clock/com.samsung.clock.views.ClockFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.initializeAnnotationDatabaseFinderAndHierarchyTraversalFilterFactory(RoboGuice.java:292)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:197)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(RoboFragmentActivity.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3754):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: @user2511882 please see.

Comment: what version of robojuice and gradle you using?

Comment: @user2511882 i do not use a gradle. I just download a **jar** from https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice